# Seven_segment possible loss precision

Tags: java, numbers, type-conversion, precision

This is my code for display seven segment but there is a problem calle possible loss of precision in this code. Please help me to solve this

```
 void ComputeDisplayValue(String value){
    SevenSeg.NumDigits = 5;
    long temp = Long.parseLong(value.substring(0,1));
    SevenSeg.DisplayValue[0] = SevenSeg.SegmentMap[ temp ];
    temp = Long.parseLong(value.substring(1,2));
    SevenSeg.DisplayValue[1] = SevenSeg.SegmentMap[ temp ];
    temp = Long.parseLong(value.substring(2,3));
    SevenSeg.DisplayValue[2] = SevenSeg.SegmentMap[ temp ];
    temp = Long.parseLong(value.substring(3,4));
    SevenSeg.DisplayValue[3] = SevenSeg.SegmentMap[ temp ];
    temp = Long.parseLong(value.substring(4,5));
    SevenSeg.DisplayValue[4] = SevenSeg.SegmentMap[ temp ];*/
    /* Suppress leading zero in 12 hour mode */            
  }
```

Comment: You need to show the actual, entire error message. Additionally, your code will be much easier for Java people to understand if you use standard Java idioms (the capitalization and such looks like C#), this looks like a textbook case for a loop, and this method looks like it belongs on the class for `SevenSeg`.

Answer (score 0):

Change all `long` and `Long` to `int` and `Integer` respectively.

Array indexes are integers, they can't be longs. Hence the error when you do

`SevenSeg.SegmentMap[temp]`

Comment: Thank you. It works. Can you tell me how to enter this code to try catch up block?